# What's the difference between determining if a network is metered using NetworkCapabilities and ConnectivityManagerCompat?

Tags: android, networking, androidx, android-networking, android-connectivitymanager

I have found that there are two ways to detect if the current network is metered:

1. With `NetworkCapabilities.hasCapability(NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_METERED)` [NetworkCapabilities](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkCapabilities)
2. With `ConnectivityManagerCompat.isActiveNetworkMetered` [ConnectivityManagerCompat](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-status-type)

So, what's the difference between these methods? And when to use each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: `ConnectivityManagerCompat.isActiveNetworkMetered` is just the `androidx` backport of the framework's [`ConnectivityManager.isActiveNetworkMetered`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#isActiveNetworkMetered()).

On platforms that have that method (API 16+), the compat version just calls the framework method directly.  Otherwise, it [tries to guess based on the connection type](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/6638ef71c9860161478a101e494ff8ebe0b1a11f:core/core/src/main/java/androidx/core/net/ConnectivityManagerCompat.java;l=99): Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, and Ethernet connections are assumed to be non-metered, while anything else is assumed to be metered.  This guess isn't necessarily correct (Wi-Fi networks can be metered, for instance), but it's the best guess you can make on that API level. You should use this in the (unlikely these days) case where you need to target API 15 or below.

As far as the differences between `ConnectivityManager.isActiveNetworkMetered` and `NetworkCapabilities.hasCapability(NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_METERED)` go: for the active data network, they are exactly the same, as the [implementation](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/c924e929cd3e62dc938fdc2a6fcd41cdeec1d5f6:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/ConnectivityService.java;l=1796) simply calls that exact method.

However, because `hasCapability` can be called on *any* network, it provides you more flexibility if you want the capabilities of networks other than the active data network.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Btw, it should be non-metered instead of metered for Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, or Ethernet connection.

Comment: Glad it helped!  That is what I meant by "anything _except_ [those] is assumed to be metered" (emphasis added) - I've expanded on that section a bit to make it clearer.